# SQL Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'PJOI015' to data type bit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union

The Error its self is not confusing but the reason why is.

My Code

```
DECLARE @Pcode as varchar(20)
DECLARE @PID as int

set @Pcode = 'PJOI015'

set @PID = (select productid from product where product.ProductCode = @Pcode and Deleted = 0)

select 'ProductCode' as Data, ProductCode as Value,'' as Other From Product where productid = @PID
Union All
select 'Descripton' as Data, Description as Value,'' as Other From Product where productid = @PID
Union All
select 'Long Descripton' as Data, FullDescription as Value,'' as Other From Product where productid = @PID
Union All
select 'Alternative Keywords' as Data, AlternativeKeywords as Value,'' as Other From Product where productid = @PID
Union All
select 'Manufactures Code' as Data, ManufacturerCode as Value,'' as Other From Product where productid = @PID
Union All
select 'Main Barcode' as Data, BarCode as Value,'' as Other From Product where productid = @PID
Union All
select 'Barcodes' as Data, Barcode as Value,
(case when BarcodeType = 0 then 'Default' 
when BarcodeType = 1 then 'Inner' 
when BarcodeType = 2 then 'Outer' 
when BarcodeType = 3 then 'Pallet' 
when BarcodeType = 4 then 'Other'
end) as Other From ProductBarcode where productid = @PID
Union all

select 'Default Supplier' as Data, Supplier.Name as Value,Supplier.SupplierCode as Other 
From Product left join Supplier on Supplier.SupplierID = Product.SupplierID 
where productid = @PID
Union all
SELECT       'Other Suppliers' as Data,Supplier.Name as Value, 'StanBuy ' + Cast(StandardBuy as varchar(10)) as Other
FROM          ProductSupplierPrice
left join Supplier on Supplier.SupplierID =  ProductSupplierPrice.SupplierID
WHERE        ProductID = @PID
GROUP BY ProductSupplierPrice.SupplierID, ProductID, StandardBuy,Supplier.Name
Union all
select 'Stocked?' as 'Data', ProductStockOption.Stocked as 'Value',branch.Name as 'Other' 
from ProductStockOption left join Branch on Branch.BranchID = ProductStockOption.BranchID
where ProductID = @PID
```

The Error

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'PJOI015' to data type bit.
```

The Confusion

```
Union all
select 'Stocked?' as 'Data', ProductStockOption.Stocked as 'Value',branch.Name as 'Other' 
from ProductStockOption left join Branch on Branch.BranchID = ProductStockOption.BranchID
where ProductID = @PID
```

If I remove the last union (Above) the code works fine.
And I can run the last union on its own but changing the @PID to the actual number.

Comment: When UNION, the selected columns' data types must match.

Comment: Downvoted this question because you didn't put effort into creating a minimal example that reproduces the problem. There is a lot of stuff in the posted code that is not relevant to your problem.

Comment: I didn't know what exactly was causing the error so how could I minimise it?

Comment: Like I said in the question the union worked without the last bit and the last bit worked on its own!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is ProductStockOption.Stocked a bit field?  Try converting it to nvarchar and see if that helps.

Comment: Yep. Now I feel stupid thanks just needed a fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: I was looking for a more complex error and overlooked the simple, Thank You